# Eclipse PDT hint popup displaying duplicate entries for some methods/globals

Tags: eclipse, wordpress, eclipse-pdt

I'm developing some WP plugin in Eclipse PDF.
Plugin itself is the Eclipse PDT project, while WordPress sources are linked to the project as library.

I'm noticed that hint popup for some methods/globals, is displaying multiple duplicate entries.

Example:

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to fix it?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have duplicate entries, because this function / constant is defined multiple times in project.

Find duplicates and add files / dirs to buildpath excludes : http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.php.help/html/tasks/configuring_build_paths.html